# JQuery animations and Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

Trying make a fadeOut animation after removing an record. In events it's look like that:

```
    'click .delete': function (e) {
        $(e.target).fadeOut(1000);
        Vals.remove(this._id);
    }
```

But this is doesn't work. How do animations properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the existing jQuery animation implementations aren't relevant for Meteor. What you'll want to do is to use the animation hooks which are automatically activated when data changes:

> https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw/j4bNvXu36IoJ

This is also better for code robustness, as you don't have to keep track of **when** to animate things, but rather just how to animate them. Here are a couple of examples:

- https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-animated-each - fades in/out and adjusts scroll position when adding/removing. Demo at http://animated-each.meteor.com/.
- https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper

Comment: can you add some example? I cannot understand it and somehow not available n meteor docs (or I miss it)

Comment: What's wrong with the linked examples? This API is not documented yet because it's not finalized. You should rest assured that some form of it will appear in Meteor 1.0, though.

Comment: Nothing wrong, just cannot understand it. Supposed that the parent._uihook is called in a div that contains more than one reactive elements, will it still work? Also, what is the definition of `insertElement,moveElement,removeElement`? Are they the animation type? Or operation done to the data type? I am confused, please help. @AndrewMao

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you're looking for?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3JRfU/

```
.on('click','.delete', function (e) {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

or

```
.on('click','.delete', function (e) {
    $(e.target).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: The question is about reactive values changing, not DOM selector / IO event based animation.