# Meteor Triggering Animation During Reactivity

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want my `<div>` to `slideToggle` whenever a reactive change occurs, but so far I cannot make it happen. I tried using JQuery in the `rendered` and `created` events of the template, but it didn't fire.

What is the proper place to trigger this? For example I have this chunk of code:

```
<div id='demo'>Hello {{name}}</div>
```

The `{{name}}` helper depends on session variable values. If the session variable changes, I want the div to `slideToggle` to reflect the changes to user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783658/jquery-animations-and-meteor) from earlier today. Meteor has introduced animation hooks for this purpose as the jquery animations generally will not work out of the box in cases where templates are being added and removed from the DOM.

Comment: I have read the exampla but still cannot really grasp the concept. Would you mind showing me a simple example?